# Wifi connected but no internet; assigned IP address, cannot connect to webpages

Tags: networking, wireless, dns

My PC is showing connected to the network, but the WiFi icon is showing a question mark over it and I cannot connect to any web pages or servers. I can get an IP address. I've tried changing DNS, I've tried restarting the network (which worked once but did not resolve the issue after it reappeared) among other attempted solutions. I tried searching solutions online to no avail. My internal card is an Intel WiFi 6 AX200 if that helps at all. To clarify, WiFi had been working for the first month or so that I've had this card

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? May be a kernel problem. State your hardware using `inxi -b`, copy the output into your question (not the comments)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`